# Is there a way to disable a specific problem warning in LatexWorkshop?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Recently I've started to experience a problem with LatexWorkshop (an extension of VScode), where the problem warning `\include should only be used after \begin{document}.` started to appear. My code example is:

```
\include{configurations.tex}

\begin{document}

   \title{title} 
   \author
   {
      \textbf{Joe}
   }
   \date{\today}
   \maketitle

\end{document}
```

I keep my configurations in the file `configurations.tex` to keep the code clean, thus I can't move it inside the `\begin` function, therefore I'm searching for a way to suppress or disable this specific problem notification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't disable or suppress this warning, you should fix the problem!

`\include` is made to include junks of the document body, it will do some magic like automatically starting a new page. What you are looking for is the `\input` macro:

```
\input{configurations}

\begin{document}

   \title{title} 
   \author
   {
      \textbf{Joe}
   }
   \date{\today}
   \maketitle

\end{document}
```